# Use low level API for getstream with Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, getstream-io

I am trying to use low level api with Laravel 5. from code I used

```
$specialFeed = FeedManager::getClient->feed('special', '42')
```

But there is no method getClient. Could you please help me how I can use low level api for getstream in Laravel?

Comment: can you add the stacktrace of the error here?

Comment: can you try getting the manager via App::make('feed_manager') as well?

Comment: <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException">FatalErrorException</abbr> in <a title="D:\GLITS\stream\stream\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php line 207" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Facade.php line 207</a>:</span> <span class="exception_message">Call to undefined method GetStream\StreamLaravel\StreamLaravelManager::getClient()</span>

Comment: what if you try to call getNewsFeeds on the FeedManager facade? does that fail too?

Comment: No, they are working Ok, But I need to find global feed (to get all feeds for all) hence need access to low level api.

Comment: I think issue is that getClient function is not there.  to via pass this I can create function in StreamLaravelManager in vendor folder but I dont think its good approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getClient` function was added on the version 2.2.2, you should make sure to pull that or a more recent version to use this functionality.

Did you follow the setup steps from the [documentation](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-laravel#installation)? In order to use the feed manager facade you need to configure Laravel accordingly.

If you that does not solve the issue, can you share more information (eg. your configurations, the version of the lib that you are using, the version of Laravel...)

Comment: Thanks for your help. yes I have followed the same steps. There is no getClient method in  StreamLaravelManager                                  following is configuration : "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "get-stream/stream-laravel": "2.2",
        "illuminate/html": "5.*"
    },

Comment: last version of the package is 2.2.3?